# Invariant on C*-algebras-number of closed unbounded derivation it admitted

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

In working of the unbounded derivation of C*-algebras. I observed the following: For topological manifold $M$, the number of closed, linear independent, unbounded derivation it admitted on $C(M)$ is exactly the dimension of $M$.

Of course this is true for smooth manifold. But I found that it may holds for arbitrary manifold.  I try to google it but seems like no positive results.  I would like to know if my result is known and well-studied. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**
By linear independent, I mean the following: derivations $\delta_{1},...\delta_{n}$ with common domain $U$ is linear independent if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\delta_{i}=0$ for $c_{1},...c_{n}$ belong to the C*-algebra, then $c_{1}=...=c_{n}=0$.

The precise statement of what I observe is: For each dense subalgebra $U$ of $C(M)$, let $N_{U}$ be the number of closed, linear independent derivation that $U$ admitted. Then the maximum of $N_{U}$ among all $U$ in $C(M)$(if exists) is equal to the dimension of the $M$.

Comment: In general, given a "nice" commutative unital algebra $A$ over the complex numbers, the object which tells you "how many" derivations there are from $A$ to other symmetric $A$-bimodules is $\Omega_A$, the Kähler module of $A$. There are functional-analytic versions of $\Omega_A$ when $A$ is a Banach or Frechet algebra and one is dealing with continuous everywhere-defined derivations. I am not sure if it is possible to set up a theory for closed densely-defined derivations from a given $A$, or whether one should restrict to some chosen dense subalgebra of $A$ like I did in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting mixed up with derivations from a dense subalgebra of $A$ to the coefficient module $A^*$, which is the setting I usually work in. I have deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion, and will write a corrected version.

Comment: Given $h\in C(T)$ define $D_h(f) = (\partial_\theta f) h$, Then $D_h :C^1(T) \to C(T)$ is continuous, linear, and satisfies $D_h(fg) =f D_h(g) + D_h(f) g$ by the product rule, so it gives a closed and densely-defined derivation $C(T) \to C(T)$. It is an exercise to check that the function $h\mapsto D_h$ is linear and injective from $C(T)$ to ${\rm Der}(C^1(T),C(T))$.

Comment: Sorry that I should make definition clear. By "linear independent" I mean the derivation is linear independent over the ring $C(M)$. So $D_{h}$ is linear dependent to $D_{h'}$ for any $h, h'\in C(T)$.

Comment: It would help if you used terminology that is more standard among a (pure) mathematical audience. Note that "linear dependence" and "linear independence" are somewhat subtle when you are dealing with modules over rings: a basic example seen in homological algebra, whose details unfortunately escape me right now, is that you can have a module M over a ring R which is generated by three elements of M, such that no two of those elements will generate M on its own, yet the three elements are not "linearly independent" over R. The relevant words here are "syzygy" and "homological dimension"

Comment: What is true is that under some natural but non-trivial restrictions on the algebra $A$, its Kaehler module is *projective* as an $A$-module, which in turn implies that locally it has a notion of "rank" (which is what you are thinking of as dimension). Then the fact that the rank of the Kaehler module of $A$ equals the "dimension" of the algebraic variety associated to $A$ is a well-known idea, although there are technical details that may need to be addressed in particular settings.

Comment: I agree with Yemon that it's still unclear what "linear independent" means. For example, there are many derivations with incompatible domains. Is it a priori assumed that the derivations in consideration have a common core?

Comment: @Ken.Wong I must be missing something. Suppose that $M$ is a closed manifold, so that the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of derivations $C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ is a left $C^\infty(M)$-module canonically isomorphic to $\Gamma(T_{\mathbb{C}}M)$, the left $C^\infty(M)$-module of smooth global sections of the complexified tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{C}}M$. Then $M$ admits a “linearly independent” (in your sense) set of $n$ $\ast$-derivations iff $M$ is parallelizable, and it admits a “linearly independent” set of $n$ derivations iff $T_{\mathbb{C}}M$ is trivial.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić I didn't noticed the fact you stated, may you provide some reference about that?

Comment: This is an easy and not particularly deep consequence of standard folklore around the Serre–Swan theorem, so I don’t think there’s a single convenient reference out there that will satisfy you. You might get some mileage from the last few chapters of Jet Nestruev’s Smooth Manifolds and Observables or chapter 2 of Ramanan’s Global Calculus.

Comment: That said, the identification of derivations of $C^\infty(M)$ with global vector fields on $M$ is fairly standard elementary differential geometry from the modern perspective.